# How to do a SELECT on a "AS" value in MySQL.

Tags: mysql

I have this query below. It delivers the names of categories and their depth in the hierarchy. The depth is an "AS" value. However, I want to be able to select on only those names which have a specific depth.  ie depth = 3.   I have googled this to death and tried creating a virtual column, but I'm not that good at sql. Any advice ? TKS !

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
    FROM nested_categories AS node,
    nested_categories AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    GROUP BY node.name
    ORDER BY depth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a HAVING clause. This is a lot like the WHERE clause but it is computed later in the process and so can work on aggregated columns:

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_categories AS node,
nested_categories AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth = 3
ORDER BY depth
```

Depending on your database engine you might need to write it as:

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_categories AS node,
nested_categories AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) = 3
ORDER BY depth
```

Comment: I never expected it to be this easy.  I spent the afternoon trying to create sub queries, and virtual columns. You are a ROCK STAR. Thank You !  FYI  I am using MySQL with Laravel.

Comment: It is not something you use all that often but when you need a HAVING clause it is hard to do without! Glad it helped you out :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT depth
     FROM ((COUNT(parent.name) - 1) 
           FROM nested_categories AS node,
           nested_categories AS parent
           WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
           GROUP BY node.name
           ORDER BY depth) AS depth
      WHERE depth=3;
```